# Como mostrar dados da BD sem usar tabela?

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela na BD que tem varias linhas para mostrar tudo numa tabela, por isso queria qualquer coisa que tivesse um cursor, para percorrer todos os dados... Tentei assim, mas não está a funcionar, podem me ajudar?

```
<?php
 ....
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT nome, telemovel, email, n_faturacao FROM Paciente");

 $dg -> set_col_title("nome", "Nome do Paciente");
 $dg -> set_col_title("telemovel", "Telem&oacute;vel");
 $dg -> set_col_title("email", "Email");
 $dg -> set_col_title("n_faturacao", "N&#186; Fatura&ccedil;&atilde;o")

 $dg -> display();

?>
```

Comment: Você diz paginação?

Comment: @MarceloBoni Como assim, não estou a perceber a pergunta, desculpe.

Comment: Sua tabela, possui muitas linhas, ou muitas colunas?

Comment: @MarceloBoni muitas linhas, neste caso tem muitos pacientes

Comment: Como assim um cursor?

Comment: @Para andar para cima e para baixo

Comment: Pode explicar o por que não esta a funcionar?

Comment: @MarceloBoni não faço ideia, o que fiz, está teóricamente correto?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61716/discussion-between-marceloboni-and-isabel-sousa).